# Can't deploy Unity Android project to Kindle Fire any longer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kindle-fire

I have a Unity project that is already successfully distributed via Google Play and Amazon Store. It runs on all the Kindle Fire devices as well. Now I have a new version, but for the life of me I can't get it to run on my Kindle Fire test device. Once I build & run, it just stops on a black screen, and the log leaves me scratching my head what might go wrong here. This is all the log being created throughout the start sequence:

```
I/ActivityStack(  258): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 pkg=de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo cmp=de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo/.CIAndroidPlugin} from pid 794
V/ActivityStack(  258): Prepare open transition: starting ActivityRecord{4180f990 de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo/.CIAndroidPlugin}
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.177231 -0.162861 9.376501
D/dalvikvm(  258): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 551K, 30% free 15332K/21703K, paused 46ms
V/ActivityStack(  258): Prepare open transition: prev=ActivityRecord{41bae778 com.amazon.kindle.otter/.Launcher}
I/ActivityManager(  258): Start proc de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo for activity de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo/.CIAndroidPlugin: pid=7240 uid=10022 gids={3003, 1015}
D/dalvikvm(  109): GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 3% free 10994K/11331K, paused 1ms+3ms
I/PhoneWindowManager(  258): repositioning status bar
D/dalvikvm(  258): GC_CONCURRENT freed 52K, 25% free 16369K/21703K, paused 2ms+7ms
D/AmazonToggle(  449): setText toggle_on
D/AmazonToggle(  449): setText toggle_off
D/QuickSettings-Wifi(  449): handleSelection Begin
D/dalvikvm(  109): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 3% free 10994K/11331K, paused 9ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  109): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 3% free 10994K/11331K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm( 7240): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 176K, 3% free 11201K/11527K, paused 18ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 7240): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.027MB for 1048592-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 7240): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 12224K/12615K, paused 3ms+1ms
D/dalvikvm( 7240): Trying to load lib /data/data/de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo/lib/libmain.so 0x415f6eb0
D/dalvikvm( 7240): Added shared lib /data/data/de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo/lib/libmain.so 0x415f6eb0
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.162861 -0.110171 10.054292
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.148491 -0.110171 10.008786
W/ActivityStack(  258): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityStack(  258): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{4180f990 de.applicationsystems.CafeIntlSolo/.CIAndroidPlugin}
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.220342 -0.119751 9.956097
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.179626 -0.086221 10.018367
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.205972 -0.114961 9.996812
D/dalvikvm(  258): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2260K, 30% free 15352K/21703K, paused 2ms+4ms
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.131726 -0.148491 10.025552
V/Sensors (  258): accel data: -0.232317 -0.100591 10.039922
```

The same project just deployed to a Nexus 7 just runs fine, even with the Amazon SDK/GameCircle setup. I already updated all the Android SDKs and the Amazon Unity Plugin, but no change. I've reset the Kindle to factory defaults and tried to install on a fresh machine, but no change. It just won't run. Any ideas how to track that down appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself:

You need at least Unity patch 4.6.1p1 from http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases. It has the following fix:

- (654591) - Android: Fixed freeze during startup on most Amazon Kindle devices.

Note that these patches are not advertised automatically. The latest announced and automatic update was. 4.6.1f1, so it requires you to take explicit action.

Regards, habitoti

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. 4.6.1p1 fixes the problem. (I think habitoti made a typo with the version)

My previous .apk only worked on the Kindle Fire HDX and not the Kindle Fire HD or original Kindle Fire.

Comment: BTW: you should actually go up to p5 (which is the latest available as of the time of this writing). I faced other issues with deployment to Sony tablets, which were only solved with p5...